# Conditional Formatting - Highlight An Entire Row by Comparing Two Cells of a Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, conditional-formatting

I've dug through the questions on this site and they address both problems I have, but separately. I've been trying to combine the solutions for a couple hours with no success.

Basically, I would like to use Conditional Formatting on Excel 2007 to compare two cells in a column AND highlight the entire row based on that comparison.

So, as an example... cells B1-B5 contain the same value, but cell B6 increases by 5 (the numbers only increase). I would like Conditional Formatting to Highlight ALL of row 5 and then highlight all subsequent changes in Row B as well.

I've tried adding a New Rule under Conditional Formatting and then the "Use a Formula to Determine Which Cells to Format" and this is my latest formula that doesn't work "=$E6=($E5>$E6)"

It seems like this should be simple, but I can't quite get it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I added an Excel tag for this question.  It would help if you could specify which version you're using.  If you're using something other than Excel, please change the tag to the appropriate software-that will definitely impact answers.

Comment: I didn't even think about it... thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming Row1 is labels, the rows are as wide as ColumnZ and you want the formatting to apply to 1000 rows try `=$B2>$B1` and apply to `=$A$2:$Z$1000` (or adjust to suit).

Edit (hopefully for clarification):

[image: SU592637 example]

Comment: The only problem there is that I need it to highlight the entire row... that seems to only highlight the single cell.